# Check which elements from one array are in another

Tags: python, numpy

I have two big data arrays [100 000 x 3] called A and B

I would like to know if any element from one array exists in the other.

Given that some mathematical manipulation was done to obtain both array they are considered to be the same if the difference between an entry in the array and the values in the other are less than 1e-9.

What is the most efficient way to achieve  this?

I have a working example with:

```
A = np.random.rand(100000, 3)
B = np.random.rand(100000, 3)
B[10] = A[10] + 1e-11
a = []
for entry in A:
    if np.min(np.max(np.abs(entry - B), axis=1)) < 1e-9:
        a.append(entry)
```

But for the size of the example this will take me a long time to check.

Comment: You can use the built-in `math.isclose()` function.

Comment: numpy has `np.allclose` to check if 2 arrays are almost the same, it has some tolerances to play with

Comment: @UlisesBussi But it only checks corresponding elements, not the cross-product.

Comment: Is the ordering of the list a of any relevance? I guess the best algorithm is to sort both arrays (1. column) or just the array B and than try to find close values, simple loop or np.searchsorted...

Answer (score 1):

Use `math.isclose()` to test if numbers are within some tolerance of each other.

Use the `any()` function to test against each element of the other array.

```
flat_A = A.flatten()
flat_B = B.flatten()
result = [a for a in flat_A if any(math.isclose(a, b, abs_tol=1e-9) for b in flat_B)]
```

You can improve the algorithm if you sort `B`. Then you can use binary search to find the close element instead of linear search.

Comment: I am getting: `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Comment: I've flattened the arrays so I can loop over them linearly.

Comment: imo it's gonna work too long, no?

Comment: As I said, you can improve it by sorting and then using binary search. Otherwise it's O(n^2).

Comment: How would you search for close vectors? (Note the code in the post that contradicts the text)

Comment: I may have misunderstood the OP's code, I thought they were looking for elements rather than rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use `KDTree`s

```
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

A_Tree = KDTree(A)
B_Tree = KDTree(B)
a = np.where([len(i) >0 for i in B_Tree.query_ball_tree(A_Tree, 1e-9, p=100)])

a
Out:        v
(array([   10,  3884,  9511, 10878, 23977, 40623, 45204, 49036, 51976,
        54020, 56403, 60273, 64507, 77374, 82695, 91806, 93235, 97881],
       dtype=int64),)
```

A high p-norm approximates the chebyshev distance metric you are looking for, and KDTree does a binary tree search between the two trees, which is much faster than sequential search methods and much more memory-saving than vectorized methods.

Comment: Fixed the tolerance

Answer (score 0):

### Blunt instrument

I think we can check intersection of rounded values to answer the question if arrays have common items:

```
accuracy = 9
intersection = np.isin(A.round(accuracy), B.round(accuracy))
common_items = A[intersection]
has_commons = intersection.any()
```

- [numpy.isin](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html#numpy.isin)
- [Numpy set routines](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.set.html)

I agree with the Barmar's comment that this is not an accurate tool. We can miss some corner cases.

### More accurate tool

This will require more time, which when using `numba` seems acceptable to me unless there are other requirements (on i3-2100 3GHz it took 4 minutes to get an answer):

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def intersect(a, b):
    '''return an array c of a.shape with c[i]=1 if a[i] is close to any item in b'''
    a_shape = a.shape
    a = a.ravel()
    c = np.zeros_like(a)
    for i in range(c.size):
        c[i] = np.isclose(b, a[i]).any()
    return c.reshape(a_shape)
```

*p.s. The question remains open: what to compare - matrix cells or their rows?*

Comment: Comparing rounded values won't find close values, because the two values might round differently. E.g. `1.9994` is close to `1.9996`, but one rounds to `1.999` the other to `2.000`

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I get your point and agree with you. Do you think we can use this as a blunt tool to quickly say "yes" to the question of whether A and B have common elements, and if "no", then use some more accurate algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the arrays to reduce complexity.

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit() #With jit approx. 30ms, without approx. 500ms
def get_simmilar(A,B):
    """
    Returns a set with the indices to A_sorted
    """
    idx_A=np.argsort(A[:,0])
    A_sorted = A[idx_A,:] 

    idx_B=np.argsort(B[:,0])
    B_sorted = B[idx_B,:]

    a=set()
    ii=0
    for i in range(A_sorted.shape[0]):
        while A_sorted[i,0] > B_sorted[ii,0] and not ii > B_sorted.shape[0]-1:
            ii+=1
        if np.max(np.abs(A_sorted[i,:] - B_sorted[ii-1,:])) < 1e-9:
            a.add(i)
        if np.max(np.abs(A_sorted[i,:] - B_sorted[ii,:])) < 1e-9:
             a.add(i)
    return a,A_sorted

a,A_sorted =  get_simmilar(A, B)
A_sorted[list(a),:]
```

Comment: It's not gonna work and here is why: `A = np.array([[1,1,1]]); B = np.array([[1-.5e-9, 1-.5e-9, 1-.5e-9], [1-.3e-9, 2, 2], [2,2,2]]); assert np.max(np.abs(B[0] - A[0])) < 1e-9; assert get_simmilar(A,B)[0]==set()`